# How can i add text to a rectangle in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles

Hi I need to be able to generate dynamic rectangles with text. I now have the problem, that im not able to add text over the rectangle

I generate the rectangles here:

```
public  void ShowAppointements()
    {
        foreach (Termin termin in MainWindow.termine)
        {
            if (termin.week == Int32.Parse(txtWeek.Content.ToString()))
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                Kalender.Children.Add(rectangle);
                Grid.SetRow(rectangle, termin.start + 2);
                Grid.SetColumn(rectangle, termin.day * 2 - 1);
                Grid.SetColumnSpan(rectangle, 2);
                Grid.SetRowSpan(rectangle, termin.end - termin.start);
                rectangle.Fill = termin.color;
            }
        }
    }
```

Looking into other similar questions the answer was always to just avoid using rectangles but idealy i would like to keep using them.

Comment: Put a TextBlock into the same Grid cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a TextBlock child to the Grid, in the same place as the Rectangle.

You could also create a sub-grid with two children, the Rectangle and the TextBlock, as follows:

```
Grid subGrid = new Grid();
subGrid.Children.Add(rectangle);
TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock();
textblock.Text = "Text to add";
subGrid.Children.Add(textblock);

Kalender.Children.Add(grid);
```

Or add the TextBlock as child of a Border, instead of having a Rectangle:

```
var border = new Border
{
    Background = termin.color,
    Child = new TextBlock { Text = "Some Text" }
};

Grid.SetRow(border, termin.start + 2);
Grid.SetColumn(border, termin.day * 2 - 1);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(border, 2);
Grid.SetRowSpan(border, termin.end - termin.start);
Kalender.Children.Add(border);
```

Or use an appropriately aligned Label:

```
var label = new Label
{
    Content = "Some Text",
    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    Background = termin.color
};

Grid.SetRow(label, termin.start + 2);
Grid.SetColumn(label, termin.day * 2 - 1);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(label, 2);
Grid.SetRowSpan(label, termin.end - termin.start);
Kalender.Children.Add(label);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yep turns out the answer was really simple and im an idiot. 
I solved it like this:

```
public  void ShowAppointements()
    {
        foreach (Termin termin in MainWindow.termine)
        {
            if (termin.week == Int32.Parse(txtWeek.Content.ToString()))
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock();
                Kalender.Children.Add(rectangle);
                Kalender.Children.Add(textblock);
                Grid.SetRow(rectangle, termin.start + 2);
                Grid.SetColumn(rectangle, termin.day * 2 - 1);
                Grid.SetColumnSpan(rectangle, 2);
                Grid.SetRowSpan(rectangle, termin.end - termin.start);
                Grid.SetRow(textblock, termin.start + 2);
                Grid.SetColumn(textblock, termin.day * 2 - 1);
                Grid.SetColumnSpan(textblock, 2);
                Grid.SetRowSpan(textblock, termin.end - termin.start);
                textblock.Text = termin.project + "\n" + termin.employee;
                rectangle.Fill = termin.color;

            }
        }
    }
```